# How can I create a user with a term reference field in a Behat test when using the Drush Driver

Tags: drush, testing

My Behat test has the following Given statement. (field_regions is a taxonomy reference field)

```
Given users:
   | name      | mail             | roles         | field_regions |
   | Joe User  | joe@example.com  | region        | Midwest       |
```

If I used the Drupal driver locally it created the user and adds Midwest to field region.  If I use Drush driver it never adds it.  I think it may be because it is an entity reference and the Drush driver can't handle this.

Comment: Is this a bug report? What's your question? How exactly can we reproduce it?

Comment: I reworded the question.  I am not sure if it is a bug. I was hoping I'm doing something wrong.